# Separate price from text

Tags: php, variables, split

today I want to ask some help:

I have this code:

```
$var = "PAYDAY 2 - Four Pack - 89,99€";
```

Now, how can I split it in two variables, one containing "PAYDAY 2 - Four Pack" and one "89,99€"?

Thanks!

Comment: Well for now I could try only something like explode() then I'll create two different variables, but I was wondering if there could be a faster way to do this...

Comment: "a faster way"? Is your question about performance issues? If it is - what is the reason to optimize this exact operation? Is it the slowest part of the project?

Comment: @zerkms, I think he means faster or better way.

Comment: @zerkms About the lenght of the code as I have to repeat this operations many times with a for cycle

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: @Roman Hudylko: put it into a function and it would take a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say :

```
$price = array_pop ( explode(' ',$var) );
```

Once you have the price, you can remove the price from the initial string.

or you could explode with the - sign.. but don't forget to remove the space in front of the price afterwards

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with regular expressions:

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/(.*) - ([^-]*)/', $var, $matches))) {
    $var1 = $matches[1]; // PAYDAY 2 - Four Pack
    $var2 = $matches[2]; // 89,99€
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/([\s\w]+-[\s\w]+)\s?-\s?([\d,]+€)/', $var, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PAYDAY 2 - Four Pack - 89,99€
    [1] => PAYDAY 2 - Four Pack 
    [2] => 89,99€
)
```